# Java program runtime error

Tags: java

```
public class Hobbits {
 String name;

 public static void main(String[] args){

  Hobbits [] h = new Hobbits[3];
  int z = 0;

  while (z<4) {
   z = z + 1;
   h[z] = new Hobbits();
   h[z].name = "Bilbo";
   if (z == 1) {
    h[z].name = "Frodo";
   }
   if (z == 2){
    h[z].name = "Sam";
   }
   System.out.print(h[z].name+ " is a ");
   System.out.println("good Hobbit name");

  }
 }
}
```

At runtime this program is giving the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Some exception, you say? Well, then something is wrong. :) (hint: be more specific)

Comment: Hi. Can you paste the exception here?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
Frodo is a good Hobbit name
Sam is a good Hobbit name
 at Hobbits.main(Hobbits.java:12)

Comment: but what has it got in its pocketses, precious?

Comment: You can use a for loop and it will do the index incrementing in a cleaner manner. Also, use `z < h.length` as the loop condition and you will never overrun an array.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with the comment, you should've been more specific, however by looking at the code I can see that your loop runs from 1 to 3 and your array has a length of only 3 (so the highest available index is 2).

Answer (score 2):

H has `h[0]`, `h[1]` and `h[2]`. You're asking for `h[3]` there :)

Answer (score 2):

Your array is 3 long.

1: Array indices start at 0.

2: Your code goes up to index 4 when 2 is the highest in your array:

```
 while (z<4) {
       z = z + 1;
       h[z] = new Hobbits();
       ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting IndexOutOfBoundsException - and it, because you are incrementing z before creating h[z] instance.
just increment in the end of the loop.

Comment: If I increment z in the end of the loop, still I am getting exception belowBilbo is a good Hobbit name
Frodo is a good Hobbit name
Sam is a good Hobbit name
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Hobbits.main(Hobbits.java:11)

Comment: Noray is right, your array has a length of 3 meaning it cna have index 0, 1 and 2. So the condition must be that z doesn't reach 3

Answer (score 1):

you need to move `z = z + 1;` to the end of the while loop

Comment: This will not solve the problem because the code will still go to index 3 with is still out of bounds.

Comment: Correct, sysout at the end will throw an exception. that should also be converted to [z-1]

Answer (score 1):

For your interest, a shorter version might look like this.

```
String[] names = "Bilbo,Frodo,Sam".split(",");
Hobbits[] h = new Hobbits[names.length];
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
   h[i] = new Hobbits();
   h[i].name = names[i];
   System.out.print(h[i].name+ " is a good Hobbit name");
}
```

The class Hobbits is redundant and you would get the same output with.

```
for(String name: "Bilbo,Frodo,Sam".split(","))
   System.out.print(name+ " is a good Hobbit name");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. move `z=z+1` to the end of the loop
2. change the condition of the while loop to `z<3`

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because of subscript error, but what is the point of having such a class?
I think that it would be a better approach to have a Hobbit class with one or two constructors some accessors and some mutators. Then it would make sense to add either a main or a TryHobbit class with a main that does its tricks with the array etc. That would provide a "cleaner" learning example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it should work.

```
int  z  =  -1
while   (z  < 2)
```